# Facebook login by sdk but post issue

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

This is what my logcat shows as a response

```
{
 Response:  responseCode: 403, 
 graphObject: null, 
 error: {
     HttpStatus: 403, 
     errorCode: 200, 
     errorType: OAuthException, 
     errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
  }, 
 isFromCache:false
}
```

I'm unable to post to facebook due to this error. What are the steps to authorize the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to issue an HTTP POST to that endpoint to publish a new feed story, facebook provides the "method=post" GET parameter to "fake" a post, this might work for you.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=TOKEN&message=HelloFacebook&method=post
```

w.r.t to response you will get an id as :

```
{
   "id": "499801468_1001264776039"
}
```

for more details please refer

for GraphAPI - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

Also  please check your permission tag

Comment: please follow the below link for implementing the updated API.

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/31232/2013/6/5/7-10